# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' reason --> unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I get this error when i play with the searchbar that I have just implemented.. Some letters work while others will crash with the error in the title. The error seems to be here but i cannot figure out what is wrong with it :

*** `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BIDPresidentDetailViewController rowImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x754e360'`
*** First throw call stack:

I have got the below code in my .m file which is giving me the above error. I am not sure as what is the error that i have made in my code:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return kNumberOfEditableRows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 75, 25)];

        label.tag = kLabelTag;
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 12, 200, 25)];
        textField.tag = kTextFieldTag;
        textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
        textField.delegate = self;
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDone:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
    }

    UILabel *label = (id)[cell viewWithTag:kLabelTag];
    label.text = self.fieldLabels[indexPath.row];

    UITextField *textField = (id)[cell viewWithTag:kTextFieldTag];
    textField.superview.tag = indexPath.row;
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case kNameRowIndex:
            textField.text = self.president.name;
            break;
        case kFromYearRowIndex:
            textField.text = self.president.fromYear;
            break;
        case kToYearRowIndex:
            textField.text = self.president.toYear;
            break;
        case kPartyIndex:
            textField.text = self.president.party;
            break;            
        default:
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    initialText = textField.text;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (![textField.text isEqualToString:initialText]) {
        hasChanges = YES;
        switch (textField.superview.tag) {
            case kNameRowIndex:
                self.president.name = textField.text;
                break;
            case kFromYearRowIndex:
                self.president.fromYear = textField.text;
                break;
            case kToYearRowIndex:
                self.president.toYear = textField.text;
                break;
            case kPartyIndex:
                self.president.party = textField.text;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Please help me here as its eating my brain and i am stuck on it since yesterday!

Comment: OK, so what does the error message "unrecognised selector sent to instance" mean to you?  It's a much asked question and you will find many examples and solutions on this site.  They won't fit your question 100% but they should give you the vital clues you need to solve this yourself.

Comment: The above code is giving me the error while trying to run the Application. I am new to objective - c and don't know as what is the mistake i have done. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  What does that phrase mean to you?  Do you think you will find any reference to it if you (gasp) searched for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that `rowImage:` is being sent to your view controller. What *should* `rowImage:` be sent to? (I'm guessing the tableView cell but can't confirm…) Once you figure out which object the message should be sent to, then correct your code.

I can't give specifics because I didn't see where `rowImage:` was being set or sent.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have integrated a plist file inside my code which contains information like "Name", "fromYear", "toYear" & "Party" info.